# Get selected columns using join two tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables. **Polls** and **Poll_likes**. Need to join and two tables and get "**polllike**", "**poll_like1**", "**poll_like2**", "**poll_like3**" and "**poll_like4**" columns from **Poll_likes** table along with all the columns from **Polls** table.

I have tried with the following query, but unable to get all the records.

```
SELECT * FROM poll_likes t LEFT JOIN polls c on c.phonenumber = t.user_Id WHERE t.`poll_id` = c.id
```

### Polls Table

[image]

### Polls Like Table

[image]

Comment: The difficulty of the problem stems from poor table design. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above 2, say) alarm bells should start ringing

Comment: I have tried with that query, unable to get all the records.